# Collapsing An Empty Ad

Tags: javascript, html, css, whitespace

I'm using an Ad service named Advoly. It's partner of Google ADx service. Here is its sample ad code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
advoly_ad_client = "xxxxx";
advoly_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxx";
advoly_ad_width = 300;
advoly_ad_height = 250;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//apps.advoly.com/proslot/cdn/ads.js">
</script>
```

Their system works like;

Whether they show ads on the site or not depends on position and importance of ad placement. That is, if you place your ad in a bad position, possibility to show ads is lower. There is a coefficient which determines this possibility.

When there is no ad because of this system, it shows an empty ad which occupies place as white space in design. How can I collapse this white space if there is no ad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it injects an iframe with the ad content? Then there is no way to detect whether the iframe has any ad content or not due to the cross origin policy. However, many ad networks allow you to specify content that should be shown if there is no ad.

Comment: They have this policy to force you to put your ads on best places. Better the place, higher the ad. Therefore, there isn't any option for empty spaces as an alternative. So, I'm looking for a code to collapse this empty spaces if it is empty. I don't know if it is possible to detect it on an iframe.

Comment: Yes, I know, that is your question and I answered it above. I will reword it: It is not possible to inspect the content of an iframe, so no. Therefore, some ad networks allow you to specify content to be displayed if there is no ad available (e.g. https://www.leadbolt.com/).